# How to implement two way Data Binding?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm

I have a class called ProfileViewModel, that consists of simple properties like so:

```
class SomeViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        private Foo foo;
        public Foo Foo
            {
                get { return foo; } 
            }

        public string Bar
            {
                get { return foo.bar; }
                set
                    {
                        foo.bar = value;
                        NotifyPropertyChanged ("Bar");
                    }
            }

            // More properties like the above

         public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
             protected void NotifyPropertyChanged (string Info)
    {
    if (PropertyChanged != null)
      {
         PropertyChanged (this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs (Info));
      }
    }
```

I removed some bits that are not really important. Now, I am trying to create a two way binding between some textboxes and the properties of the above class, but nothing seems to work. In the XAML I have tried both:

```
      <TextBox Margin="5, 25, 5, 0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="25" Name="BarField"
               Text="{Binding CurrentFoo.Bar}"/>
```

and

```
      <TextBox Margin="5, 75, 5, 0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="25" Name="BarField" 
               Text="{Binding Bar, ElementName=CurrentFoo}"/>
```

neither of which currently work (regardless whether I set it to be `Two-Way` or not), as nothing appears in the textbox, nor does changing the text in the textbox affect the CurrentFoo object. What exactly is it that I am doing wrong? What is missing here? Do I need to do the binding in the code?

Comment: Did you try with :   Text="{Binding Bar, ElementName=CurrentFoo, Mode=TwoWay}"

Comment: TextBox's `Text` property is TwoWay by default, there should be no need to specify it in the Binding.

Comment: Yeah, I edited the post because i forgot to mention that

Comment: I think you're just not binding to the correct thing... Is `CurrentFoo` a property in your ViewModel or a control in your XAML? Because your first example would bind to a property of your DataContext (viewmodel) but your second example would bind to an element in your view with that name...

Comment: Your binding is probably wrong. If you set your DataContext correctly to SomeViewModel, all you should need is `Text="{Binding Bar}"`

Comment: It is a property in the code behind. basically, it is in the .cs file for the window I am working on.

Comment: This may help : http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/rvemura.net/two-way-databinding-in-wpf/

Comment: I guess you're doing `this.DataContext = CurrentFoo` in code-behind, right? That's why simply `Binding Bar` worked, because since your DataContext is already `CurrentFoo`, you don't need to specify it as you were doing (neither with `ElementName` or on the Binding path).

Comment: @almulo I see. So if I set an object as the DataContext, it means I can just use the properties names?

Comment: Yup, that's the point of DataContext :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For your first binding to work your Foo property must be read/write, currently it is readonly.

For the second approach you do not need to set ElementName, just Mode porperty:

```
 <TextBox Text="{Binding Bar, Mode=TwoWay}"/>
```

Note: I prefer the first one.

Comment: Yeah, when I removed `ElementName` it worked. Thank you very much.

Comment: You use ElementName to refers to a named control in your View, not a property from your ViewModel

Comment: There's no need for `Mode=TwoWay`. TextBlock's `Text` property bindings are TwoWay by default.

Comment: @almulo The safest way and (best practice) is to to always be explicit what kind of binding mode you want.